# MBeans not appearing in JConsole

Tags: java, glassfish, jmx

I´m developping a java Web Application in Netbeans. Now I want to monitorize my app using jconsole.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String name="Example";

        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();

        ObjectName object = new ObjectName("org.javalobby.tnt.jmx:type=example");
        mbs.registerMBean(name, object);
    }
```

I also add the following lines to glassfish:

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myhost

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

The problem is my beans do not appear on JConsole. What I´m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing string object as an MBean object. Follow the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/tutorial/essential.html#wp1053098) as below.
Using this [blog link](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t49130.html) to create a sample test mbean.

> "An MBean is a managed Java object, similar to a JavaBeanTM, that
>   follows the design patterns set forth in the instrumentation level of
>   the JMX specification. An MBean can represent a device, an
>   application, or any resource that needs to be managed. MBeans expose a
>   management interface: a set of readable and/or writable attributes and
>   a set of invokable operations, along with a self-description.
>
> A standard MBean is defined by writing a Java interface called
>   SomethingMBean and a Java class called Something that implements that
>   interface. Every method in the interface defines either an attribute
>   or an operation in the MBean. By default every method defines an
>   operation. Attributes and operations are simply methods which follow
>   certain design patterns. A standard MBean is composed of the MBean
>   interface which lists the methods for all exposed attributes and
>   operations, and the class which implements this interface and provides
>   the functionality of the instrumented resource."

Comment: Still not working. If a create a simple Java App the blog code that you provide works. But in my Web app no.

Comment: How do you register the MBean in your web app? Through a ServletContextListener? Post the relevant code.

Comment: Andy Dufresne, tanks for your answer. My MBean appears when I make a call for the method where I implemented my register bean. That´s the reason why it does not appear. I  was just making clean and build